# Method to maximizing MPlaceolder fail, parent of MArea is null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-rap

In my project I use MArea with PartStack as Shared Elements. Perspective contains Part Sash Containers with Placeholders having references to MArea from Shared Elements.
The problem is Maximizing, press Maximize button do change icon and tooltip only. Minimize and restore after works prefect.
I found that the problem is getParent() method returns null when asking for MArea.

[img of Application.e4x](https://ibb.co/V3THqHX)

Comment: You have not really asked a question or shown us any code. If you think this is an Eclipse bug it would probably be better asked on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) but you will have to provide example code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I edit question, add img of configuration. There is no exactly code, because it's framework class only.